# MongoDB nested $lookup for 3 levels

Tags: node.js, mongodb

**MongoDB:** How to put all the subcategory in array like child_category? you can see the response, the way its coming. how to merge that clothes category of all sub_category in  array

Below is the aggregate lookup:

**$Lookup**

```
{
        $match:  { _id: ObjectId(req.params.id) }
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'sub_category',
        localField: '_id',
        foreignField: 'category',
        as: 'sub_category',
      },
    },
    {
      $unwind: {
        path: '$sub_category',
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
      }
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'child_category',
        localField: 'sub_category._id',
        foreignField: 'sub_category',
        as: 'sub_category.child_category',
      },
    }
```

Below is the response I get when run this lookup
**response**

```
[
        {
            "_id": "6219f96e2504161acb0f82a4",
            "name": "clothes",
            "__v": 0,
            "sub_category": {
                "_id": "6219fcccb2ba385797e02439",
                "name": "Shirt",
                "category": "6219f96e2504161acb0f82a4",
                "__v": 0,
                "child_category": [
                    {
                        "_id": "6219fdcd477bd10b4d4bbf12",
                        "name": "striped",
                        "sub_category": "6219fcccb2ba385797e02439",
                        "filters": [],
                        "__v": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "621a045be776b1775e9c9ec7",
                        "name": "checked",
                        "sub_category": "6219fcccb2ba385797e02439",
                        "filters": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "_id": "6219f96e2504161acb0f82a4",
            "name": "clothes",
            "__v": 0,
            "sub_category": {
                "_id": "621a0431e776b1775e9c9ebe",
                "name": "Pant",
                "category": "6219f96e2504161acb0f82a4",
                "child_category": []
            }
        }
    ]
```

I want both `sub_category` to come in array, so that `name: clothes` wont repeat in array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `$group` at the end of pipeline.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "sub_category",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "category",
      as: "sub_category"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$sub_category",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "child_category",
      localField: "sub_category._id",
      foreignField: "sub_category",
      as: "sub_category.child_category"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": {
        _id: "$_id",
        name: "$name"
      },
      "sub_category": { "$push": "$sub_category" }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WrBsJIP4bHL)

Comment: works for sub_category array.. but can we not bring like this
[
    {
       
            "_id": "621a192b699b7b71f1dd42d2",
            "name": "jewels",
        "sub_category": [
            {
                "_id": "621a3175ad737a36a9a9ebb3",
                "name": "ear",
                "category": "621a192b699b7b71f1dd42d2",
            }
         ]
}].. without wrapping id & name as object ?

Comment: this works... {
      "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "name": {
          "$first": "$name"
        },
        "sub_category": {
          "$push": "$sub_category"
        }
      }
    }